# Am not able to handle the drag and drop functionality using selenium webdriver in chrome browser

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm not able to handle the drag and drop functionality using selenium webdriver in chrome browser.

This is my piece of code:

```
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
String URL = "http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/index.shtml";
driver.get(URL);
// It is always advisable to Maximize the window before performing DragNDrop action
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='treebox1']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span"));
From.click();
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='treebox2']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span"));
To.click();
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
System.out.println("builder:"+builder);
Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(From).moveToElement(To).release(To).build();
System.out.println("draganddro:"+dragAndDrop);
dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: could you please paste your error log.

Comment: I ran your code in FirefoxDriver and it worked perfect.
Might be compatibility issue.

Comment: Hi Uday,yes this code is working firefoxdriver but it is working in chrome that is the issue could you please resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.. it will work..

```
    public void mouseOverDrag1(final WebDriver driver, By mainMenu, By subMenu) throws Exception{
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

        WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(mainMenu);
        WebElement subHoverLink = driver.findElement(subMenu);

        System.out.println(menuHoverLink.getText());

        actions.clickAndHold(menuHoverLink);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        actions.moveToElement(subHoverLink).release(subHoverLink).build();
       actions.perform();
}
```

Comment: Hi maddy,But am not understading where you are getting from mainmenu and submenu can paste that piece of code

Comment: Pass the element by locator to this function.. that is source element to mainmenu and destination element to submenu..

Comment: element nothing but just i have to pass xpath right but it is not working maddy can you please send complete code to my mail id santoshallanki@gmail.com